# Ansible script to tar folder in given dates

Tags: ansible

here's the challenge:

using ansible, I need to archive several folder into one tar file. The folder are in the format yyyy-mm-dd. A date range (i.e. start date = 2022-05-02 , end date = 2023-03-04) is given by CLI while running the ansible-playbook (--extra-var). I created a code, but somehow is stuck in generate the date ranges.

```
hosts: date-server

tasks:

  - name: Receive Start and End Date by CLI
    set_fact:
      start_date: "{{ ansible_playbook_python }} -c 'import sys; print(sys.argv[1])'"
      end_date: "{{ ansible_playbook_python }} -c 'import sys; print(sys.argv[2])'"

  - name: Generate dates for the given range
    shell: |
      #!/bin/bash
      d={{ start_date }}
      while [ "$d" != "{{ end_date }}" ]; do
        echo $d
        d=$(date -I -d "$d + 1 day")
      done
      echo {{ end_date }}
    register: dates

  - name: Archive folders of each date generated date
    shell:
      cmd: tar -cf /tmp/dates.tar /data/report/{{ item }}
      loop: "{{ dates.stdout_lines }}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script seems to work as written. Using a minimal playbook:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:

  - name: Generate dates for the given range
    shell: |
      #!/bin/bash
      d={{ start_date }}
      while [ "$d" != "{{ end_date }}" ]; do
        echo $d
        d=$(date -I -d "$d + 1 day")
      done
      echo {{ end_date }}
    register: dates

  - debug:
      var: dates.stdout_lines
```

If I run:

```
ansible-playbook playbook.yaml -e start_date=2022-05-01 -e end_date=2022-05-14
```

I get the following output from the `debug` task:

```
TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "dates.stdout_lines": [
        "2022-05-01",
        "2022-05-02",
        "2022-05-03",
        "2022-05-04",
        "2022-05-05",
        "2022-05-06",
        "2022-05-07",
        "2022-05-08",
        "2022-05-09",
        "2022-05-10",
        "2022-05-11",
        "2022-05-12",
        "2022-05-13",
        "2022-05-14"
    ]
}
```